Asset validation failed (90482) Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/OMSDK_Teadstv.framework/OMSDK_Teadstv' contains bitcode
Here are my development details:
Xcode version: 16
macOS version: 15.1
Has anyone encountered this issue and managed to resolve it with Xcode 16?
I tried multiple solutions I found online, especially the ones involving modifying the `Podfile.
